# how to search videos using you tube api that could be playable on mobiles

Tags: php, android, iphone, youtube

I have CMS where I could search and Add you tube videos on web, these videos then need to play on iPhone n andriod, there are few videos that are not playable on iPhone. I m using:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=mohamed+Said+%28exhibit&start-index=1&max-results=50&v=2 to search videos, Is there any way, so that search result could show only videos, which are playable on iPhone..
( In the Search result the first song is not playable on Mobiles )

thanks for your expert advice..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the fields parameter

" To ensure that an API response only includes videos suitable for playback on a mobile device, add the fields parameter to the API request URL with the value shown below:"

```
 fields=entry [link/@rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=mohamed+Said+%28exhibit&start-index=1&max-results=50&v=2']
```